# GKLeaderboardViewController initial leaderboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, presentmodalviewcontroller, leaderboard

When `GKLeaderboardViewController` is presented, it shows first leaderboard on the list, even if the `GKLeaderboardViewController`'s leaderboard category is not set. Only way to see the list of all leaderboards is clicking **Leaderboards** button at the top.

Is there any way to display list of all leaderboards when `GKLeaderboardViewController` is presented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set category to nil.

```
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
        //leaderboardController.category = kLeaderboardID;
        leaderboardController.category = nil;
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];
    }
    [leaderboardController release];
```

Comment: I tried nilling it, but it sometimes shows nothing but a Leaderboards button on top alone, and sometimes shows the list properly. Anyway, that's the best we can get. So I accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apple docs:

> The category property must either be nil or it must match a category
>   identifier you defined when you created your leaderboards on iTunes
>   Connect. If nil, the view displays scores for the aggregate
>   leaderboard. Default is nil.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboardViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKLeaderboardViewController/category

Comment: Apple docs are a little bit wrong. Default is not nil. If you do not nil category property, you get the default leaderboard. If you nil it yourself, you get the list of leaderboards on iOS 5, but default leaderboard is shown again on iOS 4.

Answer (score 0):

The category property is deprecated in iOS 6 and above.

Try this:

```
leaderboardController.identifier = @"Your leaderboard identifier as defined on iTunes connect";
```