# How to load the default leaderboard in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

Goal: Show the local user the default leaderboard when he/she clicks the leaderboard button in the app on their ios 7 device.

```
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:(void(^)(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error)) {

    //Use the leaderboard identifier.
    MyLeaderBoardID
}]
```

Comment: This may help: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900430/gkleaderboardviewcontroller-initial-leaderboard)

Comment: I can't figure it out. Kinda new to iOS can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Link up a UIButton to the following method to display the default leaderboard:

```
- (void) presentLeaderboards
{
    GKGameCenterViewController* gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```